# How does each function and this keyword work together in d3?[chaining transitions]

Tags: javascript, d3.js, this, each

I'm using the d3 library and having a hard time wrapping my head around some of the constructs, hoping for some guidance from experienced hands with this!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
var svg=d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",800).attr("height",1000);
svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(d3.range(10)).enter().append("circle")
.attr("cx",function(d){return d;})
.attr("cy",function(d){return d*50;})
.attr("r",function(d){return d;})
.transition().duration(4000).style("fill","red")
.each("end",svg.selectAll(this).transition().duration(4000)
.attr("cx",function(d){return d*10;}));
</script>   
  </body>
  </html>
```

From what i understand, this is supposed to create circles, then transition the colour to fill them up with red, then change the "cx" attribute for each circle. Atleast, that's what i want to do. Can someone please explain how exactly method chaining works and how to use the each() function and this keyword?

Comment: Have you studied the [API docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, your 'this' will not refer to any d3 object, because the this is evaluated within the same scope as your `<script>` tag, which, in non-strict mode, refers to the `window` object.

I suggest you try to start without the transition and then adding it gradually when you have the basics working.

The basic outline of your code is this:

1. Generate a data set based on range 1-10
2. Create a circle for each if these data objects
3. All of the objects refer to their respective value, so they are in fact numbers, which you use to calculate their position(x, y) and size (r)
4. Then you transition their background
5. Then you tell it to listen to an "end" event and execute a piece of code.

Step 5 is where it fails. I think this is basically what you want:

```
var svg=d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",800).attr("height",1000);

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(d3.range(10))
   .enter()
      .append("circle") 
         .attr("cx",function(d){return d;})
         .attr("cy",function(d){return d*50;})
         .attr("r",function(d){return d;})
         .transition()
             .duration(4000)
             .style("fill","red")
             // attach a handler to all affected objects and listen
             // to the "end" event:
             .each("end", function() { console.log(this, arguments); })
         .transition()
             .duration(4000)
             .attr("cx",function(d){return d*10;})
             // do it again
             .each("end", function() { console.log(this, arguments); })
;
```

The `transition` effect is chained by default (see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#transition)

In my experience, it helps a *lot* to think of a sensible indentation for d3, because it helps you understand what 'scope' were working on currently.

By the way, there is no random component in your code yet, so don't expect it to do any magic you don't tell it to do ;)

Comment: I got the transitions to be chained using the below code. Are they chained by default? I was under the impression that any new transition cancels out previous ongoing transitions on the same object. 
 `svg.selectAll("circle").data(d3.range(10)).enter().append("circle").attr("cx",function(d){return d;}).attr("cy",function(d){return d*50;}).attr("r",function(d){return d;}).transition().duration(4000).style("fill","red").each("end",function(d){d3.select(this).transition().duration(4000).attr("cx",function(d){return d*10;})});`

Comment: Thanks gerard, could you tell me why the meaning of the 'this' keyword changed after using it inside the anonymous function in each()?
`.each("end",function(d){d3.s‌​elect(this).transition().duration(4000).attr("cx",function(d){return d*10;})});`

Comment: That's due to javascript internals, the "this" refers to the current function scope, which can be basically anything, depending on how the library's invocation is implemented. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for a detailed description on different use cases

Comment: @GerardvanHelden `this` inside D3 functions is well-defined (and well-documented) to refer to the current DOM element. In the case OP is considering, it will *never* refer to `window`.

Comment: @Lars In the provided code in the opening post's snippet it will, because it is *not* inside of a function. Please be careful in your statements because it could get very confusing otherwise.

Comment: @GerardvanHelden You're right of course, but what I'm referring to is the intended usage. You don't mention this in your answer at all, although OP explicitly asks how to use `this`.

Comment: I see :) in this particular case this isn't actually needed, that's why I omitted it. I'll add it to the console.log call for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

The way that you go about answering questions like this is in your debugger. To be completely sure of the answer, I extracted the inline function where I could set a breakpoint:

```
function resize() {
    svg.selectAll(this).transition().duration(4000) //set breakpoint here
        .attr("cx",function(d){return d*10;})
}  

var svg=d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width",800)
          .attr("height",1000);

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d3.range(10)).enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx",function(d){return d;})
    .attr("cy",function(d){return d*50;})
    .attr("r",function(d){return d;})
    .transition().duration(4000).style("fill","red")
    .each("end",resize);
```

When you set the breakpoint, you'll see that the value of `this` is probably what you expect it to be: the current DOM element, an `'[object SVGCircleElement]'`. You might also check the `arguments` and find that the parameters passed to `resize` are `d` and `i`. That is probably not a satisfying answer since your code doesn't work.

Your next question might be how to get resize to work correctly. I don't know why  `svg.selectAll(this)` doesn't work, but if we call `d3.select(this)` , the method does work correctly.

```
function resize(d,i) {
    d3.select(this).transition().duration(4000)
        .attr("cx",function(d){return d*10;})
}
```

If you want to put resize back inline, don't forget to make your parameter a callback, not a statement:

```
.each("end",function (d) { d3.select(this).transition().duration(4000).attr("cx",d*10) });
```

Also, you can see that the documentation for [transition.each([type],listener)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each) says chained transitions (`transition.transition`) should be preferred. The standard way to implement the functionality you want is just chaining transitions:

```
.transition()
    .duration(4000)
    .style("fill","red")
.transition()
    .duration(4000)
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return d*10});
```